# TCPDF check for pagebreak

Tags: php, tcpdf

Currently i'm working with PHP and TCPDF to create PDF Files. But now i've some problems.

My PDF is divided into four columns. When i'm printing text into the first column i want to check if a pagebreak appears to increase the x position and reset the y position.

How could i check with some kind of pre-rendering is a pagebreaks appears so that i could change the x and y position so that it continues in column 2, 3, etc...

I now that their is some function like this:
[How to calculate the height of a MultiCell/writeHTMLCell in TCPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078729/how-to-calculate-the-height-of-a-multicell-writehtmlcell-in-tcpdf#answer-25303788)

But could this be used to check if there is a pagebreak or not?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the rather belated answer...
indeed there are some problems regarding the recalucation of the high of some boxes/widgets nested in vertically columns in order to display them properly.

Imagine you have 3 columns.
A => Left Column, B => Center Column, C => Right Column

Problem #1: Last Y-Position 
Depending in which order you fill your columns (for example text), your last  Y-Position is always related to your last action, this may be one of your columns with the shortly text, so if you need to draw another objects you would overlapp other objects. Therefore ist important to storage your Max-Y-Pos when drawing multiple objects (columns) vertically.

Problem #2: Check for PageBreak

Write some function/method where do you pass your Text or whatever you are displaying in that column, and column-width. For example function checkColumnPageBreak(text, columnwidth) 
Given those both parameters and your current Y-Position you should be able to   determine if your resulting position exceeds you Max-Page-Height, mostly 280pixel. Once you get to next page you are not able to write to previes one, so you may be forced to break your text into two separate blocks, where the last one will be written when all columns have been wrote.

There are some functions around there, maybe this is what you need:
https://gist.github.com/johnballantyne/4089627

Based on the assumption that your column is an multicell, all you have to do is to pass your column width, cellheight, and your text.